# How to do dependent nested loop using itertools.product?

Tags: python, python-itertools

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i + 1, n):
```

How to do this using [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)? It takes a variable number of iterables, but there doesn't seem to be a way to reference one iterable from another.

For example, `n=5`:

```
for x in itertools.product(range(5), range(1, 5))
```

generates

```
(0, 1)
(0, 2)
(0, 3)
(0, 4)
(1, 1)
...
```

Note `(1, 1)` is not supposed to be there.

Comment: It's not clear what "reference one iterable from another" means. Do you mean "how do you tell Python which one is i and which one is j"?

Comment: @Acccumulation It should be plenty clear from the nested for loops that you need to reference the outer loop from the inner (`i+1`).

Comment: BTW, `i` isn't an iterable. `range(5)` is an iterable, and `i` is a particular value from that iterable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a given `n`

```
n = 5

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i + 1, n):
        print((i, j))
```

Prints:

```
(0, 1)
(0, 2)
(0, 3)
(0, 4)
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(1, 4)
(2, 3)
(2, 4)
(3, 4)
```

This isn't a Cartesian product, which is what itertools.product produces.  It is a combination which can be made with [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations, product

tups = list(combinations(range(5), r=2))
```

`tups` will be:

```
[(0, 1),
 (0, 2),
 (0, 3),
 (0, 4),
 (1, 2),
 (1, 3),
 (1, 4),
 (2, 3),
 (2, 4),
 (3, 4)]
```

Comment: You're right about the cartesian pdt. The docs say "_Roughly equivalent to nested for-loops_", so that misled me a bit.

Comment: I agree @AbhijitSarkar that could be a little more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can do `itertools.combinations(range(5),2)`. The `range(5)` tells it that the elements range from 0 to 4, and the `2` tells it that each tuple has 2 elements. If you want to access the elements within each tuple, you can do indexing:

```
for x in itertools.combinations(range(5),2):
    i = x[0]
    j = x[1]
```

or you can list the variable names in the for-loop:

```
for i, j in itertools.combinations(range(5),2):
```